# Any filter-like lambda operation which does not discard?

Tags: java, lambda, java-8, java-stream

I basically would like to do something like:

```
  assertEquals(Arrays.asList(1,2,3).stream()
                                   .noDiscardingFilter(x -> x!=1)
                                   .map(x -> x*10)
                                   .collect(Collectors.toList()),  
                Arrays.asList(1,20,30)
              )
```

This is an example, I don't need to get an answer on how to solve out that particular problem, it's just an example to show what's the fancy stuff I'm coming after.

Comment: Why not do that in the map() intermediate op?

Comment: Just asking if theres any operation or trick like that

Comment: *I don't need to get an answer on how to accomplish the problem, it's just a practical way to show what's the fancy stuff I'd be happy to know about*. Can you define/quantify what you mean by *fancy* for us then?

Comment: @CKing: I think, it’s about separating predicate and function, which might have a much higher relevance if they are much more complex that these simple examples.

Comment: exactly! You nailed it

Comment: @Cking I think you misunderstood me. What I want to say is I don´t want someone to solve the particular example with loops or other approaches (usual in SO), this is just a simplification to show the kind of lambda operation I am after

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Any intermediate step affects the entire stream pipeline. There is no recognizable rule behind your wish that the `noDiscardingFilter` step affects what the subsequently chained `map` will do, but not the `collect` operation. If you want to have a conditional function, it would be much clearer to implement it as such:

```
public static <T> Function<T,T> conditional(
                                Predicate<? super T> p, Function<T, ? extends T> f) {
    return obj -> p.test(obj)? f.apply(obj): obj;
}
```

This can be used as

```
assertEquals(Stream.of(1, 2, 3)
        .map(conditional(x -> x!=1, x -> x*10))
        .collect(Collectors.toList()),
    Arrays.asList(1, 20, 30)
);
```

or

```
Stream.of(1, 5, null, 3, null, 4)
      .map(conditional(Objects::isNull, x -> 0)) // replacing null with default value
      .forEach(System.out::println);
```

or

```
Stream.of(1, 5, null, 3, null, 4)
      .map(conditional(Objects::nonNull, x -> x*10)) // null-safe calculation
      .forEach(System.out::println);
```

Note how in these use cases, it is immediately recognizable that the predicate and function passed to `conditional` belong to the same scope, which is different from the chained stream operations.

Answer (score 3):

If you want to only change the entries which match the filter but retain the rest.

```
assertEquals(Arrays.asList(-1, 1, 20, 30),
             Stream.of(-1, 1, 2, 3)
                   .map(i -> i <= 1 ? i /* retain */ : 10 * i /* transform */)
                   .collect(Collectors.toList()));
```

Comment: Exactly. That's the idea. That was my original proposition, but as the logic is quite complex I thought of  better asking if there was some operation for filtering like that