# Conditional method call in the map method java 8

Tags: java-8, java-stream

```
Persons = personDao.getFileInformation(filePath)
                    .skip(1)
                    .map(this::getPerson)
                    .filter(person -> person != null)
                    .collect(Collectors.toList());

getFileInformation(filePath) returns Stream<String>
```

after reading lines in a file.

I would like to replace the getPerson method with a **getMale** or **getFemale** method based on the value of an enum

```
public enum gender {
male,female
}
```

How can this be achieved used lambda expressions?

Comment: what does getMale and getFemale return each? a person? or a Male/Female object?

Comment: @Eugene: I’d interpret this question like in your (deleted) answer, however, it doesn’t seem to be worth the effort if the questioner doesn’t care anyway…

Comment: @Holger I actually hoped it will get some attention, because I really wanted to say that using a method reference like: `return p.getGender() == Gender.MALE ? this::getMale : this::getFemale;` does not compile. I have not dug any deeper, but I hoped that once the attention was there, I would.

Comment: @Eugene: well, whenever you are going beyond a plain method invocation, method references stop working, however, `.map(p -> p.getGender() == Gender.MALE? getMale(p): getFemale(p))` is simple enough and bringing `::` somehow into it wouldn’t make the expression simpler. You could create a helper method similar to [this one](http://stackoverflow.com/a/42030215/2711488), just with two `Function`s, still, using it isn’t more concise than a lambda expression.

Answer (score 3):

If you just want to filter by gender (assuming there is an accessor like `Person.getGender`), then you only need to add a `filter`:

```
List<Person> malePeople;
malePeople = personDao.getFileInformation(filePath)
                      .skip(1)
                      .map(this::getPerson)
                      .filter(Objects::nonNull)
                      .filter(p -> p.getGender() == gender.male) // or gender.female
                      .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

If you rather want to group your results, the following will help you:

```
Map<gender, List<Person>> peopleByGender;
peopleByGender = personDao.getFileInformation(filePath)
                          .skip(1)
                          .map(this::getPerson)
                          .filter(Objects::nonNull)
                          .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Person::getGender));
```

now access all your female people with:

```
List<Person> femalePeople = peopleByGender.get(gender.female);
```

and the male ones with:

```
List<Person> malePeople = peopleByGender.get(gender.male);
```

If you just wanted to use a method to simplify the filter-predicate (`p -> p.getGender() == gender.male`), then you could use one of the following:

```
.filter(this::getMale) // or: YourClass::getMale for a static method
```

where `this::getMale` refers to the following method:

```
boolean getMale(Person p) {
   return p.getGender() == gender.male;
}
```

or

```
.filter(getMale())
```

where `getMale()` refers to the following method:

```
Predicate<Person> getMale() {
  return p -> p.getGender() == gender.male;
}
```

Comment: You may wish to consider the cost it comes when to use skip(). Refer https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#skip-long-