# Conditionally transforming Stream elements when predicate matches

Tags: java, java-stream

I have a stream and want to apply a method only if a predicate matches.

E.g. I want to process a stream and replace all `null`s by a default value. What is the best way to accomplish this?

Comment: With a simple loop?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/q/42029357/2711488

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should just use a map value

```
data.stream()
    .map(v -> v == null ? defaultValue : v)
    ... // do whatever you need to do with it.
```

**EDIT**

If you need to do this a lot you could create a Function to do it for you.

```
public class DefaultValue<T> extends Function<T, T> P{
    private final T t;
    public DefaultValue(T t){
        this.t. = t;
    }

    public T apply(T t) {
         return t == null ? this.t : t;
    }
 }

 data.stream()
     .map(new DefaultValue(someValue));
     // Do what you need to do
```

Answer (score 2):

If you are looking to preserve the original values for items that do *not* match your filter, use `map` with ternary logic:

- Items that do not pass filter are returned as-is
- Items that pass the filter get transformed

Here is an example:

```
Stream<String> stream = Arrays.stream(
    new String[]{"quick", null, "brown", "fox", null, "jumps"}
);
List<String> res = stream
    .map(s -> s != null ? s : "<EMPTY>")
    .collect(Collectors.toList());
for (String s : res) {
    System.out.println(s);
}
```

Filtering logic is embedded in the conditional expression inside `map`:

```
s -> s != null ? s : "<EMPTY>" // Using default values for null strings
```

[Demo.](http://ideone.com/HPyD3D)